# Amazon Beanstalk Web Server with Self Signed certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it possible to start Amazon Beanstalk Web Server in SSL mode with the Self Signed certificate?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.

You first need to create a self signed certificate first as described by the article below
http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

and then you need to upload the certificate using aws iam command line tools (http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/4143):

iam-servercertupload --aws-credential-file ./aws-credential.txt -b www.example.com.crt -k www.example.com.key -s www.example.com-2012 -v